# v-autocomplete reloads page on "Enter" click

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I use [v-autocomplete](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/) on my page and when the cursor is in v-autocomplete controle and I click on "Enter", the page is realoading.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: page shouldn't be reloaded by default, Maybe you're adding it inside `form` component and it has a post submit function ?

Comment: Can you share the code. By default it will not reload. You can test that in this official documentation https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should add to v-autocomplete:
**@keydown.enter.native.prevent**